# What does my .htaccess file mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

My .htaccess says the following:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName eigos.co.nz
AuthUserFile /home/bob/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /home/bob/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

Could someone please tell me what all this is doing?

Answer (score 7):

When you are looking for documentation on apache question the best thing to do is type "apache ${command}" i.e. "apache IndexIgnore" into google. The first result is usually the apache documentation. If you are doing any apache configuration you need use the docs. (Which are rather nice)

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
```

When displaying an auto-generated index, hide files in the following masks.

Documentation: 
AutoIndex Module, 
IndexIgnore

```
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
```

For get and post request allow all traffic. With order deny, allow the server applies deny directives first (deny all) and then applies allow directives (allow all) on top of any denies.

Documentation: 
Limit, 
Order

```
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
```

For put and delete request deny access to all addresses (*.*.*.*)

```
AuthName eigos.co.nz
```

This effectively sets the title on the username/password prompt the browser shows. I do not know any effect beyond that.

Documentation: AuthName

```
AuthUserFile /home/bob/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.pwd
```

File containing usernames and password hashes.

Documentation: AuthUserFile

```
AuthGroupFile /home/bob/public_html/_vti_pvt/service.grp
```

List of groups of users

Documentation: AuthGroupFile